# how to set backbone model value without it delaying?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to build a zoom in zoom out slider and buttons with jquery ui and backbone, but I've run into an interesting problem. I've made it the job of the model to set the zoom value, so that all you have to do is call that method in the view, and it handles the value update, but the problem is, when I do that it will lag one behind... what i mean is the start value is 8 you will press the zoom in button and you'd think the zoom value would go to 9 but it lingers at 8 then the next time you click the button it goes to 9, and the next time you click it it goes to 10... and so on, but this lag causes a strange problem. Because I've set a max and a min value for the slider I'm checking to make sure that the zoom value stays within those bounds. but because there is this delay if you would... it will get to one below the max value and not allow you to increase it, but if you decrease the value by clicking the zoom out button it will, on the first click, change the value up to the max then on the second click it will go down to to 15 (one below the max) so I'm very confused why this is happening. any help on this would be greatly appreciated... I've included the code relevant to this problem below. if you don't understand something that I've said or have a question... I will do my best to answer.

these are the views:

```
var SliderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "slider-vertical",
    events: {
        "slidechange": "updateVal"
    },
    initialize:function(){
        this.model.on('change:zoom', this.update, this)
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            min: 1,
            max: 16,
            value: 8,
        })
        return this; 
    },
    updateVal:function(ev){
        var val = this.$el.slider("option", "value");
        this.model.setZoom(val)
    },
    update:function(){
        this.$el.slider('value', this.model.get('zoom'))
    }
});

var ZoomInButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "zoom-in-button",
    events: {
        "click": "update"
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.button();
        return this;
    },
    update: function(ev) {
        this.model.incrementZoom();
    }
});

var ZoomOutButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "zoom-out-button",
    events: {
        "click": "update"
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.button();
        return this;
    },
    update: function() {
        this.model.decrementZoom(); 
    }
});

    // this is the view that handles all the events and sets everything up... and it gets called by main.js
var ZoomControllerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".wrap",

    // this renders all the sub views. 

    initialize:function(){
        this.model = new zoomModel
        this.slider = new SliderView({model: this.model}); 
        this.zoomInButton = new ZoomInButtonView({model: this.model});
        this.zoomOutButton = new ZoomOutButtonView({model: this.model});
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.slider.render().el);
        this.$el.append(this.zoomInButton.render().el);
        this.$el.append(this.zoomOutButton.render().el);
    }
});
```

This is the model:

```
var ZoomModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // we set a default start zoom of 8 
    // so it's right in the middle.
    initialize: function() {
        this.zoom = 8;
    },
    setZoom: function(val) {
        if (val > 0 && val <= 16) {
            this.set({zoom: val}); 
        }
    },
    incrementZoom: function() {
        if (this.zoom < 16) {
            this.set({zoom: this.zoom++});
        }
    },
    decrementZoom: function() {
        if (this.zoom > 1) {
            this.set({zoom: this.zoom--}); 
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "incrementZoom" and "decrementZoom" methods the value "this.zoom" returns to "this.set" method before you change it. It is a problem in your case. Just do this:

```
incrementZoom: function() {
    if (this.zoom < 16) {
        this.set({zoom: ++this.zoom});
    }
},
decrementZoom: function() {
    if (this.zoom > 1) {
        this.set({zoom: --this.zoom}); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @AlexW.H.B.: Remember that `++x` increments `x` and then returns the (incremented) value of `x` whereas `x++` returns the value of `x` and then increments it. The left-to-right order of the `++` and `x` indicates the order that things happen in.